# Just can't autostart tomcat in Ubuntu. What's wrong?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, autostart

I tried two ways:

1. Add the following in etc/rc.local:

   export JAVA_HOME=/home/phoenies/jdk1.6.0_17
   export JRE_HOME=/home/phoenies/jdk1.6.0_17/jre
   export CLASSPATH=.:/home/phoenies/jdk1.6.0_17/lib/*
   /home/phoenies/scarab-0.21/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
2. Run this:

   ln -s -t /etc/init.d /home/phoenies/scarab-0.21/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
   mv /etc/init.d/startup.sh /etc/init.d/tomcat
   update-rc.d tomcat defaults 99

Neither worked. I've made sure all scripts have the permission to run. I've checked with `sysv-rc-conf` that rc.local and tomcat would run in runlevels 2-5. And I can startup tomcat manually by double-clicking either of them. Anyone knows why tomcat still doesn't autostart?

My OS is Ubuntu 9.04, Tomcat 4.1 is included in Scarab 0.21 as you can see.

**Edit:** I've just checked all runlevels in `sysv-rc-conf`, and this time it worked! I'm not familiar with the concept runlevel. Would someone kindly explain what runlevel my OS is running on? And what are other runlevels for? Thanks.

**Reedit:** `runlevel` told me the current runlevel is 2. I don't understand... :(

Comment: Does it log an error or not even start?

Comment: you mean in tomcat/logs/? No log there.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `startup.sh` doesn't have executable bit set.

```
chmod +x startup.sh
```

I have seen this issue with at least couple of software packages which bundle Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Runlevels are to start different things at different points in the start sequence.
You can also use them as a sort of partial reboot.

Tradiationally they are:

1. Single-User mode
2. Multi-user mode console logins    only (without networking)
3. Multi-User mode, console logins
4. Not used
5. Multi-User mode,    with display
6. Reboot

and 0 = halt (but SO's list wont do 0 because Jeff doesn't know 'C' )

For ubuntu/debian based Linux they aren't used as much, the system always runs in 2.
the startup is handled by a program called 'startup'